# Quarterly Top User, showing spurious changes

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, reputation-leagues

I am not sure if this is known or even if this is the right place post it. However, I think the reputation *Quarterly Top User* page has a bug in it:

[image]

His change is `143,200`, yet his reputation points are only `7,494`.

https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/quarter/stackoverflow/2018-01-01/1612975#1612975

Comment: It is the change in his ranking, not the change in his rep.  Still smells funky, but this page has a lot of known bugs that they don't want to fix.  Something to do with querying a dbase while it is being updated by normal site traffic.

Comment: @HansPassant ahh ok, well that might make more sense. thanks

Comment: Related on Network Meta: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95648/rank-change-so-big-increase and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170003/how-to-read-the-user-reputation-leagues-table

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like Hans commented (and because this doesn't seem to be answered yet on MSO), this is the *rank* change from last quarter, not a *rep* change. You can see what each number is for by looking at the associated label below each column:

[image: Rank and rep change circled in red]

It's not super obvious, but columns 2 and 4 refer to the change in the thing being measured in columns 1 and 3, respectively.

Comment: Yeah i can see how the large jump can be attributed now. Thanks